# This will be the third time I've job hopped this year. Boss is overseas. I want to make sure I am resigning correctly

Tags: resignation, notice-period, australia

I start the new job in Jan 9. I need to provide 1 weeks notice to my employer. My work at my current employment is mediocre and I think it would be best for both myself and the company to forego the formality of the 1 week and cancel my employment. Furthermore, my superior is overseas, although he is checking his email.

I was thinking about submitting the resignation as follows:

- Sending an email to my superior (the CTO) and possibly the HR explaining that despite having a good start with the company, I don't see myself there long-term, and have decided to accept an opportunity elsewhere which is very much in line with my interests.
- Suggesting that we forego the formality of 1 week notice as my work isn't crucial for business continuity.
- Instructions in where I deposited the work that I have completed.
- That I will be deleting all company intellectual property from my laptop and will not use any further resources unless explicitly contacted and requested to work the final week.
- My contact number and email address in-case they need to contact me.

I've decided that I do not need to notify the recruiting company, but I am sure they will contact me and ask why I decided to leave.

My biggest concern is that I will be sending the resignation letter over email, and because I don't have any physical company property, I won't be going in to the office.

Is there anything else I should do, or is this sufficient? The company has my bank account details for depositing my first and final cheque and superannuation (as required by Australia).

Comment: *Much* too long. Please try and cut this down to a few paragraphs at most, with one (and only one) clearly specified question for the whole thing.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - thanks for the suggestion, I've removed most of the fluff, and tried to ask a pointed question, do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - The office is staffed only with my peers aside from my boss who is overseas. I need to provide notice as my new job starts on Jan 9 - and he returns to the office early January. The only other person I can hand notice to officially is HR. Which I'm not opposed to doing, but she's not my superior. -- which as I write this, is probably the best option including the email to my boss.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I should still have a written record that I submit via email/to HR correct? Contacting the boss is fine, but I need to make sure that this is confirmed, including the known end date of my work period. Since Australia is not at-will, you must serve out the final week, and if not served the company has the advantage of taking 1 week out of your final pay. I understand part of it is professionalism, but I have worked a certain amount of time and produced work which I want to be paid up to. As for continuing employment, that is really up to the discretion of the company. 1/2

Comment: I do think it is best for the company to let me go early. Although if they want me to stay, I will perform to the best of my ability as expected. 2/2

Comment: Eh, I don't think you're paying attention to what I'm saying. I'll follow through with your suggestion, but I will definitely be sending an email as well. I don't want to mince words when I resign and I want to make sure the dates are specified in advance.

Comment: "Not mince words" sounds like you want to tell your boss off. BAD decision, for reasons already discussed here many times. Job hopping already has you in a bad position. Pissing people off gratuitously will make that worse.  Don't confirm and compound your user name. If you want to be treated like a professional, behave like one.

Comment: You start Jan 9.  What is the problem with a 1 week notice?

Comment: @Paparazzi - Due to holiday seasons, my boss (the only person I report to in the company) is overseas. I've come to the decision that I will contact him first, and then follow up with an email for formality sake (which is what I mean by "not mincing words"). It isn't as bad as I think, but I just want to make sure they don't dock my pay for the hours I've already worked, and I'm known to screw these formalities up - as evidenced by the previous position that I walked out on in the last week. Despite sounding somewhat agitated, I actually appreicate all of oyur advice on such short notice.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you want to forego the one week? Even if you craft the best argument, they can enforce you to work the week.

Surely you just do the week, document any handover and start the new role next year? I don't get why you wouldn't do the week, apart from the fact you don't want to.

Stick to the terms of your contract, and you can't go wrong. You'll get paid for your time as all contractual obligations have been met.

Comment: "You'll get paid for your time as all contractual obligations have been met." .. And you won't burn any bridges :)

Answer (score 2):

Your arguments for why they should let you go sooner are irrelevant unless the company, through your management chain, agrees with you. **You need to convince them, not yourself and not us. That means discussing it with someone who can make that decision.**

If you try to make this decision unilaterally, you will almost certainly leave people significantly unhappy. That may come back to hurt you if you are ever job searching again.

It costs very little to give adequate notice. If the new employer would jettison you for meeting your business obligations and starting a few days late, I agree that you really don't want to work for them; if they care that little about treating folks with respect, that does not bode well for how they will treat you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give notice to your boss or to HR, you give notice to the company. For example, you might send your notice by registered mail to the company's registered address. Whether the post office can't deliver because the address doesn't exist, or whether company refuses to accept the letter, or whether they accept it and leave it until the boss returns, it is legally received by the company at the day the post office tried to deliver it. That's if you are worried about the legalities. If you are worried about leaving a good impression, talk to your boss.

And in the future, if a recruiter can't move a starting date by one day, they better have a very, very good reason why not, or you don't take the job. Say they want you to start on July 1st and you can't start until July 2nd: If you don't take the job, they are most likely not going to get anyone starting for a few weeks.

Comment: That last paragraph hit me hard. I have learned a valuable lesson from this (and yes I was legally docked a week worth of pay because of this blunder, and rightfully so considering how distasteful the act was). Thank you for the advice. I think I will do this in sequence by first talking to my boss, and following up in writing by email to himself and HR.